# compute the tableau's nonbasic term in SCIP separator

Tags: mixed-integer-programming, scip, simplex-algorithm, pyscipopt

In traditional Simplex Algorithm notation, we have x at the current basis selection B as so:
x<sub>B</sub> = A<sub>B</sub><sup>-1</sup>b - A<sub>B</sub><sup>-1</sup>A<sub>N</sub>x<sub>N</sub>. How can I compute the A<sub>B</sub><sup>-1</sup>A<sub>N</sub> term inside a separator in SCIP, or at least iterate over its columns?

I see three helpful methods: `getLPColsData`, `getLPRowsData`, `getLPBasisInd`. I'm just not sure exactly what data those methods represent, particularly the last one, with its negative row indexes. How do I use those to get the value I want?

Do those methods return the same data no matter what LP algorithm is used? Or do I need to account for dual vs primal? How does the use of the "revised" algorithm play into my calculation?

Update: I discovered the `getLPBInvARow` and `getLPBInvRow`. That seems to be much closer to what I'm after. I don't yet understand their results; they seem to include more/less dimensions than expected. I'm still looking for understanding at how to use them to get the rays away from the corner.

Update 2: further code at https://github.com/scipopt/scip/issues/31

Answer (score 0):

you are correct that `getLPBInvRow` or `getLPBInvARow` are the methods you want. `getLPBInvARow` directly returns you a of the simplex tableau, but it is not more efficient to use than `getLPBInvRow` and doing the multiplication yourself since the LP solver needs to also compute the actual tableau first.

I suggest you look into either `sepa_gomory.c` or `sepa_gmi.c` for examples of how to use these methods. How do they include less dimensions than expected? They both return sparse vectors.